# How to have foreach contains dynamic element

Tags: php, oop, for-loop, foreach

Here is my Foreach, How can i assign different class each time consequently

Here is what i have tried so far.

```
<?php
$class1="one";
$class2="two";
$class3="three";
$class4="four";
foreach ($blogs as $blog)
 {
  echo $blog->val;
  echo $class;
 }
?>
```

Here the foreach behaves regular as it might contain any number of records.

But i need to assign the $class as one, two, three, four consecutively (which is defined above the foreach).

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by defining $class as an array

```
$class = array(
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
);
```

Iterate your blogs array retrieving the key as well

```
foreach ($blogs as $key => $blog) {
    ....
}
```

Then use the modulus operator `%` against the `$key` value within your loop to identify each entry from `$class` in turn

```
foreach ($blogs as $key => $blog) {
    echo $blog->val;
    echo $class[($key % 4)];
}
```

Use the modulus with a division by `4` because there are 4 entries in your `$class` array

Comment: A (slight) variation of this approach is using a separate variable as a index. At each step this variable is 1) checked against size of `$class`; 2) dropped to zero if it's equal; 3) processed (via `$class[$i]`); 4) incremented.

Comment: @raina77ow Can you post it as an separate answer please.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, there are two more approaches; both use `$classes` containing all the possible values. First is a slight variation of @MarkBaker's answer:

```
$classes = array('one', 'two'/*, ...*/);
$length = count($class);
$i = 0;
foreach($blogs as $blog) {
  echo $blog->val;
  echo $classes[$i];
  if (++$i === $length) {
    $i = 0;
  }
}
```

Second makes the `$classes` check as direct as possible - through [**array_chunk()**](http://php.net/array_chunk):

```
foreach (array_chunk($blogs, count($classes)) as $blogs_chunk) {
  foreach($blogs_chunks as $key => $blog) {
    echo $blog->val;
    echo $classes[$key];
  }
}
```

In this case it's not necessary to check for overflow/modalize because each chunk contains not more than `count($classes)` elements.